# Where can I ask for feedback on my concept?

Tags: support, on-topic-definition, asking-questions, stackexchange

I thought out a software architecture for a larger application I'll be working on. Before actually starting to code, I'd like feedback on the architecture. Since this is about the needs of *only my project*, I think it won't fit this site.

Where can I ask this kind of feedback questions?

Comment: To add to Yannis' answer, if you have some questions/doubts about specific aspects of your architectural design, Programmers is most definitely the right place to ask those questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If what you have in mind is a kind of architecture / design review question, then technically, those questions would be a bit "too localized"<sup>1</sup>. However, we do have a [sister site dedicated to code reviews](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), and it's doing just fine. I don't see why we couldn't at least try to find a way to make architecture / design reviews work on Programmers.

I'd say... go for it, and let's see what happens. I can't promise you the community will respond favorably to your question, but if you don't mind experimenting (and risking a couple of downvotes and/or a closure), you should just ask it. If it works, great, if it doesn't, hey at least you tried.

Obviously, as with any other question, you should do your best to be as clear and concise as possible, and give us every essential detail.

<sub><sup>1</sup> SE lingo for overly specific questions that don't apply to a wider audience.</sub>